# How to fix: Varnish not enabling on Apache

Tags: apache, varnish, varnish-vcl

New server setup, but testing Varnish, after installation, does not show the expected result. It does not look like Varnish is configured correctly for Apache.

The server is CentOS 7, running Apache 2.4, Redis, RabbitMQ and Varnish 5.2.

I have followed the instructions to change Varnish listening port to 80, and changed backend defaults to `.port ="8080"` in `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` and `VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80` in `/etc/varnish/varnish.params`

```
backend default {
    .host = "164.160.89.188";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

when I restart Varnish and Apache and run the command 
curl -I http://localhost
I get the following results:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 12:45:59 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 30 Jan 2019 02:03:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
```

I should be getting something like this

```
X-Varnish: 13
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v5
```

Varnish Status shows the following

```
varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-06-12 13:40:35 SAST; 3h 25min ago
 Main PID: 4074 (varnishd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/varnish.service
           ├─4074 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
           └─4084 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m

Jun 12 13:40:35 server2.co.za systemd[1]: Starting Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator...
Jun 12 13:40:35 server2.co.za varnishd[4074]: Platform: Linux,3.10.0,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Jun 12 13:40:35 server2.co.za varnishd[4073]: Debug: Platform: Linux,3.10.0,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Jun 12 13:40:35 server2.co.za varnishd[4074]: Child (4084) Started
Jun 12 13:40:35 server2.co.za varnishd[4073]: Debug: Child (4084) Started
Jun 12 13:40:35 server2.co.za varnishd[4074]: Child (4084) said Child starts
Jun 12 13:40:35 server2.co.za systemd[1]: Started Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Apache sends a Pragma header, the quick fix is to write "unset beresp.http.Pragma" in vcl_backend_response and it will unset the pragma header and start caching content, but you might want to check why Apache sends the header.